# Can the news feed returned by Facebook Graph api be changed to show Most Recent stories?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the current (v2.4) Graph api I can see a user's news feed at `/{user-id}/home` assuming I have the user access token and the `read_stream` extended permission.

As per the [Facebook developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/home), "The posts returned by this API may not be identical to the posts a person would see on facebook.com or in Facebook's mobile apps."

Is there any way—probably undocumented because I can't find it in the official docs—to modify what is returned? e.g. to emulate the Show Most Recent Stories option on facebook.com?

Or to limit the posts to those published by white-listed users, for example?

(I would *like* to be able to access the public posts of a user's friend. I can't do it via the friend's `{user-id}/feed` even though the posts are public because of FB's privacy-related API restrictions, but I was hoping to be able to do it via the News Feed, which will only work if the full News Feed is available rather than the limited Top Stories feed returned by default.)

Note: I know similar questions have been asked on SO before but they either haven't been answered categorically or relate to earlier versions of the API.

Comment: Both `/{user-id}/home` endpoint and `read_stream` permission are deprecated, and will be removed for all apps (no matter what API version they are using) on October 6, 2015 – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations If you want to get posts by the user’s friends, then those friends have to become users of your app and grant it access to their posts first.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I had missed that looking at the documentation.

I was looking for a categoric yes or no, although it's not the answer I was hoping for. I don't know why they deny API access to content that is freely available on facebook.com, it makes an interesting project non-viable. (Btw, I would have accepted your reply if you'd posted it as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `/{user-id}/home` endpoint and `read_stream` permission are deprecated, and will be removed for all apps (no matter what API version they are using) on October 6, 2015 – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

If you want to get posts by the user’s friends, then those friends have to become users of your app and grant it access to their posts first.

---

> I don't know why they deny API access to content that is freely available on facebook.com

Presumably mainly because you are not a Facebook *user* here viewing content that other people have made accessible to them, but a *3rd party app developer* – and in that capacity, you could do all sort of (shady) things with that data if it was freely available to you, like do extended social profiling, data mining, etc. Therefor users must now explicitly agree to share content with your app, before you can access it.
It’s also why they removed all `friends_*` permissions that existed previously, that allowed people to grant apps access to data belonging to their friends to a certain extend.

Basically it boils down to this: Whether or not a 3rd party app gets access to *my* data should be *my* decision, and not that of any Facebook friends of mine.

Comment: I slightly disagree. I think the privacy pendulum has swung too far in the opposite direction in this case. If I publish something on facebook and mark it as public, then it is out there in the wild. If I'm concerned about who can see my updates, I should have privacy set to friends-only. Nothing to stop an unscrupulous developer scraping facebook.com for the public data. My use case is our local mayor uses his facebook account to publish council policy/activity, and I want to make those updates available to anyone without obliging them to use FB and friend the mayor.

Comment: Privacy is perhaps not the only factor here, but also that FB wants to make money with their ads they inject into newsfeed – and that’s why they don’t want to have 3rd party apps replicate “core functionality” such as news feed any more.

Comment: Anyway, your mayor should perhaps not publish that kind of stuff on their personal wall in the first place, but publish it to a dedicated Facebook Page set up for your town/community. Posts made to a page you can still get relatively easy with an app.